# Elasticsearch Python passing result of scanner to bulk writer

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm reading from one ES environment and writing to another.  For various reasons this is the only available solution at the moment.  I sent up a scanner like this.

```
elastic_source = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
    "https://sourceHostName.com:9200",
    http_auth=('elastic', 'changeme'))

scanner = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(elastic_source, query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
                                          index="the_index")
```

Can I pass the results of this scan helper to the bulk writer?  If so, how?

Comment: elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk(client, actions, chunk_size=500, raise_on_error=True) ?

Comment: @DejanMarić that would require me to iterate through the entire scanner to build action objects. There's something like 10m objects in these indices.  I think I have a solution I'll post in answer but I haven't had much of a chance to test it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elastic_source = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
    "https://sourceHostName.com:9200",
    http_auth=('elastic', 'changeme'))

scanner = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(elastic_source, query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
                                          index="the_index")
scan_result = ({
                         "_index": _index,
                         "_type": result['_type'],
                         "_id": result['_id'],
                         "_source": result['_source'],
                     }, for result in scanner)

elasticsearch.helpers.bulk(elastic_destination, scan_result)
```

This will allow one to directly pass the generator created from scan method to the bulk writer method for consumption.